# Deferred/async task with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action in which I send a request to a web service. The web service takes FOREVER to respond and my users are waiting ages to get a response back from us.

The web page that I display to the user is NOT dependent upon the response from the web service. I'd like my request to the web service to be deferred/asynchronous so that my users don't have to wait for the roundtrip to the web service.

What should I do? What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/defunkt/resque.  It's a delayed job library for doing exactly what you need.  Built by one of the Github founders and a lot of people are known to use it.

An alternative would be https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: Note that collective_idea on Github has been maintaining DelayedJob for quite some time now. And in all honesty, *DelayedJob* is probably better suited for the simple case that it sounds like Harry has here. Resque is (and they state this) for when you need performance, multiple queues, etc.

Comment: Good point.  The URL to the proper delayed job repo is https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: You're probably right on the DJ vs Resque statement, although the learning curve for resque isn't too bad.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using workers?

Is there a way to say "respond to the request and then immediately do this task"? It would be nice to not have to implement some queueing system.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  But I agree, it would be nice if a queueing system weren't required, but given the single-threaded nature of Rails, this is not possible.

Comment: @Harry You *could* fork off a script in the background, but it'd be a lot less flexible and scaleable.